# Basic Gauss Elimination yields wrong result?

Tags: error-handling

I was reading a book and got stuck at a particular point. I stuck here in the following and want to know that how x+(y+z)=0.0 calculated ?
[image]

Further in the following example of Gauss elimination method I couldn't get how 2.5/(-0.005)=-2500 got calculated? From where they took this "-0.005" value .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Julius :) I will remember the edits for my future posts :)

Comment: I don't understand why few people just love to down vote ? It's upsetting and insensible ,the real gems are those who help and support like Eric and Julius here but the ones who just down voted this post are simply unworthy to this beautiful platform of collaboration :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers do not do arithmetic in the same way that people do on pen and paper.  Numbers have limited precision.  Imagine you had a number system where you could only have 4 digits after the decimal point and also a factor of 10 to some power, and so numbers looked like:

```
±0._ _ _ _ × 10ⁿ
```

Now, add these two numbers:

```
 0.1234 × 10⁸
 0.5678 × 10⁰
```

You are adding

```
12340000
```

and

```
00000000.5678
```

The real sum is

```
12340000.5678,
```

but the theoretical computer here can store only the first four digits, giving

```
12340000 = 0.1234 × 10⁸
```

That is why `y+z` in the textbook problem is equal to `y`, and `x + (y + z) = 0 ≠ (x + y) + z`.

```
x =  0.1 × 10¹⁰
y = -0.1 × 10¹⁰
z =  0.1 × 10¹

x + y = 0.0
(x + y) + z = 0.0 + 0.1 × 10¹ = 0.1 × 10¹
```

(Single-precision) floats have only 8 digits of precision in IEEE arithmetic.  These correspond to the C `float` datatype. But `y = - 10⁹ z`, and `z` disappears when you add `y` and `z`.  So,

```
y + z = -999999999 = -0.1 × 10¹⁰ after rounding.
x + ( y + z) = 0.0
```

The book also has a typographical error.  The quotient should have been `2.5/(-0.001)`, from rows 2 and 3, column 2 of the matrix.

This is why computer algorithms for matrix algebra are tricky; they seek to minimize the effect of roundoff error and underflow. Unfortunately, any flaw in an algorithm can lead to very bad problems.  One test is to look at the *Hilbert matrix*

```
H_n = (1/(i+j-1))     1 ≤ i, j ≤ n
```

The inverse of this matrix is has integer entries, but that matrix and its inverse are spectacularly ill-conditioned.  Any numerical error in computing the inverse will lead to wildly-wrong values.  Twenty years ago, I tested the inverse routine for the then-current version of Matlab.  It was acceptable for H_10, but too poor to use for H_12.

Comment: First of all thanks for your explanation .I know that what concept applied here but I was actually confused that why and how x+(y+z)=0.0 got calculated .It would be great if you can explain that in steps .further according to your suggestion i was right that there was a typographical error Because otherwise there was just no reason to put 0.005 there .Thanks again !

Comment: `y` is just too much larger than `z`, and so `y+z` loses all the digits of `z`, just as the sum in my example end up losing all of `z`.  So, `(x+y) + z = 0 + z = z` because `x+y` is computed *first*.  On the other hand, `x + (y + z) = x + y = 0` because `y + z` is computed first.  No matter how much one knows by reasoning, it's always useful to run through a computation at least once.

Comment: Thank you so much .It's totally clear to me now  :)

Comment: You can look at the *Numerical Recipes in X* books to see practical treatments of problems like these in your chosen computer language.  I also recommend the fun *Numerical Methods that (Usually) Work*, by Forman Acton.  That one is old-fashioned; he worked in the 50s and 60s.  But a programmer who has limited resources must analyze his problems carefully, which makes his insights more valuable.  Still, the specialized libraries like BLAS and LAPACK are the most important for linear algebra work.